# How to run Intellij IDEA 12 as a 64 bit process on Win7?

Tags: intellij-idea

Have anyone tried this? I got one problem here.
I have seen this post http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1185 and done as what it said. But seems it doesn't work on my PC. Here are the system variables and Java version.

System variables:
[image]

Java version:
[image]

When I clicked "idea64.exe", an error occurred:

[image]

You can see "IDEA_JDK" in the first image. It has already been set, right? Even though I add "IDEA_JDK_64", the same error still happens.

As last, I tried "idea.bat" to see the exception details:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version n
umber in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:12
4)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
```

Seems it's due to inconsistent Java version between IDEA and OS. Should I update JDK to 1.6 or higher? If I want to keep using 1.5, how could I do?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the latest stable (11.1) version of IDEA requires JDK in version 1.6 or higher as defined [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/system_requirements.jsp?os=win). You're trying to run even more recent version so IMO chances that it'll run with 1.5 are slim.

Comment: Also it seems to reason that you can keep programming for 1.5 while using 1.6+ as the runtime for IDEA. Keep your 1.5 as system default (in the JAVA_HOME environmental variable) but install a separate instance for IDEA (and set IDEA_JDK_64 to that new instance).